# Zooming in and out on canvas

Tags: html, canvas, zooming, html5-canvas

I wrote a paint application using the HTML5 canvas element.

Now I want to give the user an option to zoom in and out while painting.

How can I do this?

Comment: How have you implemented your paint application?  What data will you have available to redraw the canvas at a greater or lesser zoom?  If all you want to do is make the existing pixels bigger then scale it with CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few ways. It really depends on what you're looking for.

You could do it by scaling the entire context, as in `ctx.scale(2,2)`, and then redrawing everything at this larger scale. Several things drawn, like paths and text, will scale gracefully. To accomplish this you will need to keep good track of everything drawn so far.

Another way is to take the entire canvas and draw it back to itself. This requires a temporary canvas because the operation is really: Draw to temp canvas, clear main, draw back to main scaled.

Another way is to use CSS transforms to merely zoom the canvas itself, which will make the image blurry (its zoomed!) but does not require changing any of the pixels already on the canvas.

Comment: Just wanted to add that after each transformation (e.g. scaling), the new situation is default. What I mean with that is that doing `ctx.scale(0.5, 0.5)` after setting it `(2, 2)` will actually do `(2 * 0.5, 2 * 0.5)`, and hence setting it to `(2, 2)` and then to `(0.5, 0.5)` will not smallen the actual canvas compared to what it was initially, but rather reset it to its previous sizes.